# How to format a table inside a Matrix special?

Tags: tables, matrices, mathematics

I hope I could find a solution to make something similar to this:
[image: Data Matrix]

I couldn't add `D=\left(` and `\right)` to this table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Data matrix format}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l|cccc}
     & $X_1$      & $X_2$      & ...                     & $X_d$      \\ \hline
$x_1$ & $x_{11}$ & $x_{12}$ & ...                     & $x_{1d}$ \\
$x_2$ & $x_{21}$ & $x_{22}$ & \multicolumn{1}{l}{...} & $x_{2d}$ \\
...  & ...       & ...       & ...                     & ...       \\
$x_n$ & $x_{n1}$ & $x_{n2}$ & ...                     & $x_{nd}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `array` environment is essentially a `tabular` environment geared for math mode.  So use that instead.  Then, adding all the other required math stuff occurs naturally.

Also, `\dots`, `\vdots`, and `\ddots` are available for use in math mode.

Finally, I removed the `\multicolumn`, as I did not see anything it added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Data matrix format}\medskip
\label{my-label}
$D = \left( 
\begin{array}{l|cccc}
       & X_1    & X_2    & \dots  & X_d    \\ \hline
x_1    & x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots  & x_{1d} \\
x_2    & x_{21} & x_{22} & \dots  & x_{2d} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_n    & x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \dots  & x_{nd}
\end{array}
\right)$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that, I appreciated

Comment: @sysmonet You are welcome.  For aligning things in math mode, the `amsmath` package generally provides superior environments for accomplishing it (with the proper math spacing), But when you want to add various horizontal and vertical rules, as is the case here, the `array` environment  generally proves most versatile.